# how to fix AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'strip'?

Tags: django, forms, validation, django-forms

Error in forms.py and i don't know why my validation doesn't work! help me
when i complite register he gives me this error

It's a shame that I'm doing everything according to the examples that work for other people, but I do not, although everything is absolutely the same!

I will wait with impatience)!

```
    Traceback:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PANDEMIC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\PANDEMIC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\PANDEMIC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PANDEMIC\Desktop\td11\newstudio\accounts\views.py", line 15, in signup
    if form.is_valid():
  File "C:\Users\PANDEMIC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 183, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\Users\PANDEMIC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\PANDEMIC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 386, in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
  File "C:\Users\PANDEMIC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 396, in _post_clean
    self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)
  File "C:\Users\PANDEMIC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1233, in full_clean
    self.clean()
  File "C:\Users\PANDEMIC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 349, in clean
    self.email = self.__class__.objects.normalize_email(self.email)
  File "C:\Users\PANDEMIC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 29, in normalize_email
    email_name, domain_part = email.strip().rsplit('@', 1)
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

forms.py

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    error_messages = {'email_is_not_exists': "This email is not exists, please SignUp For free!", "wrong_password":"Wrong Password!"}

    class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ("username", "password")

    def clean(self):
        username        = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password        = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user            = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if not user:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This user does not exist!")

        if not user.check_password(password):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect password!")
        if not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This user is not longer active!")
        return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
def login_view(request):
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    title = "LogIn"
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
    context = {"title":title, "form":form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', context)
```

html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container" >
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <div class="row" >
            <form method="POST" > {% csrf_token %}
                <h3>LogIn</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
                <div/>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter password"/>
                </div>
                <div class="text-xs-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">LogIn</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

model

```
class User(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username                                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    email                                       = models.EmailField(default=True)
    photo                                       = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_photos/", default=None,width_field="width_field", height_field="height_field")
    width_field                                 = models.IntegerField(default=150)
    height_field                                = models.IntegerField(default=150)
    first_name                                  = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=True)
    last_name                                   = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=True)
    password                                    = models.CharField(max_length=80, default=True)
    is_active                                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser                                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp                                   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated                                     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.username

    class Meta:
        ordering                                = ["-id"]
        verbose_name                            = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural                     = 'User'
```

Comment: Please show the *full* traceback, not a snippet from it.

Comment: can you check pls

Comment: Now you've just shown a different snippet. Show the whole thing. (And remove the template, that's irrelevant.)

Comment: Doing `User.objects.get(email=email)` will raise `DoesNotExist` if the user does not exist. You could do `check_email = User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()` instead. In your `clean_username` method you should return `username`, not `email`.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks for the advice, I took it into service) but still the same mistake (

Comment: In that case, you should [edit] your question to show your current code and error.

Comment: No, all the same error, in the description everything is written!

Comment: remove the save part from your modelform once and try to save your form

Comment: @Exprator, nothing changed!